# Permanently set keyboard layout

Tags: keyboard

I have a Spanish language keyboard made by Logitech and I want to set it as the default keyboard layout in Ubuntu for WSL. `dpkg-reconfigure Keyboard-layout` does not offer my keyboard model in the list of keyboards supported.

Comment: You mean your keyboard is not working? You don't need to see your specific keyboard normally in order for it to work (Generic 101-key PC is ok) and to set the default one (the one set during installation).

Comment: @cipurus Then it becomes very difficult to find special characters. The Ubuntu installation process does this nicely when installing on a bare machine but this is not available for Ubuntu installed in a virtual environment such as a VM or WSL.

Comment: What I mean is special characters come with the keyboard **layout** not with the keyboard **model**. For the model you can keep Generic 101-key PC (no need to select Logitech etc there), you just need to select your desired Spanish keyboard layout. Is that missing?

Comment: @cipricud dpkg-reconfigure does not let one know that that is possible so I was nor aware of the possibility.

Comment: What is worse is that my password uses characters that have special locations on a Spanish keyboard different than on a generic keyboard so I am unable to login to Ubuntu.

Comment: `not available for Ubuntu installed in a virtual environment such as a VM or WSL`: why not? In a virtual environment the stages of installation are the same. Anyway, the default keyboard layout can be changed by adding a new one and putting it first in the list of kb. layouts.

Comment: Virtual environments normally use pre-built binaries so one does not get the opportunity to specify a keyboard layout.

Comment: you have to give more details within the question. what is the default layout of your ubuntu? English? can't you type with your spanish kb in order to log in? you just have to identify the corresponding keys. For example I type now in English using English layout on a French keyboard. Most of the characters are the same (only A is Q and a few more.)

Comment: I consider it a major defect in Ubuntu if I have to continually guess where characters are. My keyboard is Spanish but the language for Ubuntu is English.

Comment: You just have to do it in order to log in: then you can change the language there to a Spanish layout corresponding to your keyboard.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88304/discussion-between-cipricus-and-jonathan).

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the reason `dpkg-reconfigure` failed was that it was necessary to run `sudo apt upgrade` first. Doing this solved everything.